# Is Xcode incorrectly correcting my const-correctness in C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, constants, warnings, const-correctness

I'm making my own string class, which I have just started, and I have typed up the following so far.

```
class My_String
{
    char const* characters;
    My_String(char const* _string);
    void setString(const char const* _string);
};
```

---

In my `My_String` method declaration, the argument has no `const` at the beginning, whereas my `setString` method declaration does.

(Note: I intend to have `const` at the beginning of `My_String` as well, however I don't in this example for comparison.)

---

I want a `const` at the beginning of the argument because I don't intend to change `_string` in the method.

However, Xcode gives me a warning (not error), underlining the second `const` (adjacent to `*`) of `setString`, with a suggestion "`Duplicate 'const' declaration specifier`", and offers to delete it for me.

---

Why does it do this? As far as I know, the 2 `const` serve different purposes, and therefore are not redundant.

Comment: What `init` are you talking about? Anyway, xcode is right. You have one too many `const`s.

Comment: `My_String(char const* _string)`.

Comment: But one `const` is for constant pointing, the other is for not changing value.

Comment: Why duplicate? Has this question indeed been answered?

Comment: `const char*` is the same as `char const *`.

Comment: See http://cdecl.org or the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) for reading declarations. `_string` is a pointer to const char const. The reason it doesn't make much sense is because there's an extra `const`.

Comment: @juanchopanza -- Then how do I make it such that the pointer is constant AND the stuff its pointing to is unchangeable?

Comment: Read the duplicate? Although a top level const in a function parameter gets ignored in a function signature, so you'd only need it in the implementation.

Comment: So what I really want is `char const * const`?